# Android download image with Workmanager and show it in gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I wrote code that downloads some source of data from the internet (in this example picture), shows downloadPercentages while the process of downloading is ongoing and writes this file on android storage. works well and looks very nice everything except saving on android storage.

Code is written in 3 classes, but I will show only one that I think is relevant (DownloadWorker). If anyone thinks other classes might help, let me now in comment and I will add them.

DownloadWorker:

```
class DownloadWorker(val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

companion object {
    const val FILE_NAME = "image.jpg"
}

override fun doWork(): Result {
    try {
        if (DownloadHelper.url == null) {
            DownloadHelper.downloadState.postValue(DownloadState.Failure)
            return Result.failure()
        }

        DownloadHelper.url?.apply {
            if(!startsWith("https")) {
                DownloadHelper.url = replace("http", "https")
            }
        }

        val url = URL(DownloadHelper.url)
        val connection = url.openConnection()
        connection.connect()
        val fileSize = connection.contentLength
        val inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        val file = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val outputFile = File(file, FILE_NAME)
        var len = 0
        var total = 0L
        val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

        len = inputStream.read(buffer)
        while (len != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len)
            total += len
            val percent = ((total * 100) / fileSize).toInt()
            DownloadHelper.downloadState.postValue(DownloadState.InProgress(percent))

            len = inputStream.read(buffer)
        }

        fos.close()
        inputStream.close()
        DownloadHelper.downloadState.postValue(DownloadState.Success(outputFile))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        DownloadHelper.downloadState.postValue(DownloadState.Failure)
        return Result.failure()
    }

    return Result.success()
}
```

}

After download success, my image is not shown in gallery, or in downloaded files folder. To see this image you need to enter android storage, find in android data app package by name and navigate all the way to the image. Pretty complicated.
Can anyone help, thanks.

Comment: `my image is not shown in gallery, ` Indead as getExternalFilesDir() is private to your app. The 'gallery' -whatever that is- has no access to that location.

Comment: `or in downloaded files folder` Which folder do you have in mind? Full path please. Compare path with path you used.

Comment: Use Media related apis on/above Android Q+ & MediaScanner on below to make images directly indexable by the Gallery.

Comment: @blackapps my current path is "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.practicing/files/Download". The path I want to add is standard download folder of android system. I tried to find it on my mobile phone and some of downloaded pictures are saved on this path "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/"
But I don't want to hardcore any path, I want to find the command to tell android to save image on standarnd download folder of any device

Comment: @DarShan I just tried scanFile() function from this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634950/downloaded-image-showing-in-android-studio-but-not-gallery

and imageToGallery() function fro this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428120/save-to-gallery-android

but neither solved the problem...

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Download is path to public Download directory. You get this path using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

Comment: @blackapps well done, it does show image now thank you! If you want write answer outside of comments, I will accept and upvote it